# How to read json format using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have json format like this

```
{
    "data1": {
        "name": "acong",
        "status": {
            "kawin": "Ya",
            "Keterangn": "Udah Kawin"
        },
        "data2": [{
            "id": "1",
            "nama": "Bali"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "nama": "Jakarta"
        }]
    }
}
```

how to output in html using jquery ?

Comment: in which format in html?

Comment: in html select option tag

Comment: All of the properties or just `data2`?

Comment: just data2 @dork , how to get value

Comment: the result is undefined

`$.get("datajson.php", function (data) {
data = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(data.nama);
});`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [valid JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) string you can parse it with javascript like this:

```
var jsonString = '[{..},{...},...]';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

And then, iterate over the generated object like this:

```
for (var item in obj) {
   var objItem = obj[item];
   // Do your stuff here ...
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

This snippet creates an option list from data2 object:

```js
var obj = {
      "data1": {
        "name": "acong",
        "status": {
              "kawin": "Ya",
              "Keterangn": "Udah Kawin"
            },
        "data2": [
          {
          "id": "1",
          "nama": "Bali"
          }, 
          {
          "id": "2",
          "nama": "Jakarta"
          }
        ]
    }
};


// Get the object that contains the options
var data2 = obj['data1']['data2'];

// Iterate over this object
for (var item in data2) {

  var opt = data2[item];

  // Append an new option element for every object node
  $('#sel').append($('<option value="' + opt.id + '">' + opt.nama + '</option>'));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if its json object sent from server, do it like this

```
var data = {
        "data1": {
            "name": "acong",
            "status": {
                "kawin": "Ya",
                "Keterangn": "Udah Kawin"
            },
            "data2": [{
                "id": "1",
                "nama": "Bali"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "nama": "Jakarta"
            }]
        }
    };
console.log(data)   ;
console.log(data.data1) 
data.data1.data2.forEach(function(d,index){
console.log(d.id);
});
```

in html output like this

```
$("#someelement").html("<strong>"+data.data1.name+"</strong>");
```

Comment: my json not assign into variable
how to get result using jquery and append to select option tag

Comment: use jquery ajax to fetch the data and return the response from server as JSON object , than you can use the result object as JSON object . checkout this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

loop through object using `$.each()` - create html and append it to any div or element

```js
var data = {
"data1": {
    "name": "acong",
    "status": {
        "kawin": "Ya",
        "Keterangn": "Udah Kawin"
    },
    "data2": [{
        "id": "1",
        "nama": "Bali"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "nama": "Jakarta"
    }]
}
} ;

var html = "<select>";
$.each(data,function(i,x) {
    $.each(x.data2,function(i_inner,x_inner) {
        html += "<option value='"+x_inner.id+"'>"+x_inner.nama+"</option>";
    });
});
$("#container").html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: how to assign variable with json ?
i get json from API
and i get json like this 
`{
    "data1": {
        "name": "acong",
        "status": {
            "kawin": "Ya",
            "Keterangn": "Udah Kawin"
        },
        "data2": [{
            "id": "1",
            "nama": "Bali"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "nama": "Jakarta"
        }]
    }
}`

Comment: are you fetching data using ajax?

Comment: i trying with your code and work. thank you very much

Comment: Okay :)  Dhara Parmar